# Increasing counter in TimerTask

Tags: android, timertask

How can I increase my counter i here:

```
private void startTimer() {

    int i = 0;
    final Timer timer = new Timer();
    final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            if(preferences.getBoolean(IS_RUNNING_KEY, false))
            {
                final int k = i++; //i must declared final error
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timeCounter.setText(""+k);
                        Log.d("DTAG","K: "+k);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();

            }
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 1000);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "increase my timer"? Do you mean increasing `i`?

Comment: Yep, fixed the question

Comment: Declare `i` as a class field, outside of any method.

Comment: Everything declared as final can't be re-assigned. If you want to make the counter can be re-assigned, you must make the counter as a member variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `i` out of the scope of the function. Then it does not have to be declared final and you can change it. Change your code to this

```
private int i = 0;
private void startTimer() {

final Timer timer = new Timer();
final TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {


        if(preferences.getBoolean(IS_RUNNING_KEY, false))
        {
            final int k = i++;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timeCounter.setText(""+k);
                    Log.d("DTAG","K: "+k);
                }
            });
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();

        }
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 1000);

}
```